# EcomDev Phpunit tests called twice during execution

Tags: php, magento, phpunit, magento-1.7, ecomdev-phpunit

I am trying to run few unit test cases and I see that they are being run twice in each run, I am not sure of the reason though.

The following is my test case structure -

```
class Sample_Module_Test_Model_HelloserviceTest extends EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case{

 public function testHelloworld(){
  Mage::log("Hello world!");
 }

}
```

And, I execute the test by

```
 phpunit --group Sample_Module
```

This is what I see

```
PHPUnit 3.7.22 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /mnt/www/dev.giftcardmall.com/phpunit.xml.dist

......

Time: 2 seconds, Memory: 26.75Mb

OK (2 tests, 0 assertions)
```

Also in the log I see Hello world printed twice on every execution.

I am not sure where I am going wrong...any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All unit test execute twice?

Comment: @Thiha Yes, I added few more now, and all of the is executing twice. Well one of the test cases is to create a magento website and it executes twice - second time fails throwing an exception that website with same code already exists

Comment: Same problem here. (i'm on phpStorm Win7)

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably executing the tests due to incorrect arguments like:

```
phpunit -c tests/ -c tests/phpunit.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never. I had the same problem, but only now bothered to investigate.

In my case I had the wrong groups defined in my config.xml. I had my groups defined in singular node names, but they should be plural. So instead of:

```
<phpunit>
    <suite>
        <modules>
            <Module_Name />
        </modules>
        <groups>
            <model>Model</model>
            <helper>Helper</helper>
            <block>Block</block>
        </groups>
    </suite>
</phpunit>
```

It should be:

```
<phpunit>
    <suite>
        <modules>
            <Module_Name />
        </modules>
        <groups>
            <models>Model</models>
            <helpers>Helper</helpers>
            <blocks>Block</blocks>
        </groups>
    </suite>
</phpunit>
```

But you could also just leave the groups node out. You only actually need it if you have your tests in another directory.